# CSOM File current version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I have a design requirement to show current File version. From what I can tell File object does not have a Version Number property and SharePoint basically does not consider current File state as a version? To get that work one would have to do the following I was thinking:

```
clientContext.Load(file, f => f.Versions);
FileVersionCollection fileVersionCollection = file.Versions;
int currentFileVersion = fileVersionCollection.Count + 1;
```

Right now I have File.Versions as on optional field to get initialized within a method. I wanted to keep optional so can omit if design does not need Versions in order to improve query performance. So if we cannot get current version from File obj directly want to call that out as design issue was thinking. However, if there is a way to get current version directly from File obj without initializing File.Versions please let me know (*maybe I overlooked a field*)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no vesion property in File object. We have to initialize File.Versions to get the file version.

And to get current file version, we use `FileVersion.IsCurrentVersion` property to check it:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee539266(v=office.15)

Below is an article for your reference:

https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/get-current-version-of-file-in-sharepoint-using-csom

Comment: Thanks for confirming File obj does not have a property similiar to FileVersion.VersionLabel.  I did notice the FileVersion.IsCurrentVersion property and will be sure to add that. Trying to invision a use case for it as File.Versions does not appear to contain current File? Perhaps if there are no versions of the File yet then only one version which would be current version?